# Mock class instantiated in constructor of other class in Gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A() { b = std::make_shared<B>(this); }
    void method() { b->methodB(); }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
};

class B
{
public: 
    ...
    void methodB() {}
};
```

I want to test if methodB is called from method. How to mock class B in order to make this possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate how `b = std::make_shared<A>(this);` should actually work without `A` being a derived class of `B` and `b` not being a `std::shared_ptr<B>`?? Your code example doesn't make any sense for me, sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ typo, sorry. I edited question right now :)

Comment: `B b;` still isn't a `shared_ptr<B>` and your code still doesn't make any sense. Maybe you abstracted the real problem a bit too far here.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see that, because I have written this to be correct, just to show what I need. So basically one typo more. But my question isn't about that. It's about gtest mocks.

Comment: Does that make sense in 1st place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes ? Because your code won't compile, no regards using a mock or not.

Comment: No, because code from project doesn't have any errors, it works, and now I want to cover it with GTests, because of future changes.

Comment: In other words: Get `A() { b = std::make_shared<B>(this); }` compiled 1st, before asking about gtest mocking. Post a [mcve].

Comment: If you can change `A`, you could have its constructor(s) accept a `BFactory` instead of creating its own `B` object.

Comment: I do not see polymorphism in the sample. The problem is that mocking relies on dynamic polymorphism and any code that doesn't follow that rule will be hard (and ugly) to mock.